# Class Library (Package) and NuGet Packages

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I made a new Class Library (Package) project in VS 2015 and added a reference to Microsoft.Owin package, however I can't access the Microsoft.Owin namespace.

This is my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Class1 Class Library",
  "authors": [ "sebastiano.roncato" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.Owin": "3.0.0",
    "Owin": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't even add a reference to a library in same solution. Since this a preview template, they still might be working on this

Comment: I am also getting this issue